# Dynamically change image size

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a picture constantly but cannot seem to find relevant results.
For instance, I have a picture of 50px (width) by 100px (height) and I want to change the width from 25px to 100px and the height from 50px to 200px (so image stays width divided by height).

How would I do that and is it possible (I guess it is)?

Here a the basic code:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div class="image"><img src="http://libcom.org/files/images/library/black-square.jpg" width="50px" height="100px"/></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.image {
    position:fixed;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jELqu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the size immmediately, you can just set the CSS style with javascript:

```
var img = document.querySelectorAll("#container .image img")[0];

img.style.height = "200px";
img.style.width = "100px";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bh94J/

---

If you want the size to change gradually, you can use CSS3 by also specifying this CSS:

```
.image img {
   -moz-transition: height 3s, width 3s;
    -webkit-transition: height 3s, width 3s;
    transition:  height 3s, width 3s;
}
```

as seen in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6YTmt/

Comment: @PMint - seems to be working just fine to me.  What did you expect to see that you're not seeing.

Comment: It does not constantly change the size, i.e. every 0.1 sec the size lowers by 1 pixel. Also, I'm sorry if the OP isn't clear, difficult to explain.

Comment: @PMint - where in your question do you ask for a constantly changing size?  I don't see that.  You would either user `setInterval()` to apply a small change every few ms or you would use CSS animations/transitions.  Please clarify your question.  It is not clear what you want.

Comment: @PMint - here's a version that does a gradual change using CSS3 transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6YTmt/

Comment: @PMint - added version to my answer that changes the size gradually.  Unsure what you are really asking for in your question.

Comment: Perfect! Now if possible it should go smaller too and randomly higher and lower.

Comment: @PMint - I think I've shown you the general idea for how to do this (twice).  The idea of StackOverflow is that you ask a question and we answer it.  If you try to deploy this code and you have a more detailed follow on question, you can ask another question with those specifics in it.  The idea of StackOverflow is not that you just keep adding more onto your question expecting us to keep adding more onto our answers.  That's not how it works.  It is now your turn to take what we've given you and try to adapt it to your exact needs.

Comment: I didn't intend to add more and more, looks like my question was just didn't really tell what it wanted. Anyway, good job, I can make it how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jELqu/4/

Use `<yourImg>.style.height` and `<yourImg>.style.width` for setting new values.

Comment: Ok, now I want that without the button and not just from 50x100 to 100x200 but from 50x100 to 51x102 to 52x104 etc.

Comment: @PMint: You should use that code as callback bound to any event, for example: on image hover, please read the documentation for browser's DOM events, and how to handle those.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function to do the scaling.
For example:

if you would like to re-size the picture to the width of 200 pixels and height 300 pixels
you could do something like this:

first create a function, let's name it `function scale(e)`. This function will get a 
parameter which is the image object you want to re-scale.

At the function we can get the `style` property of the image object and change the `width` and `height` as you can see below.

Now we need to call the function and provide the image object like this: `onclick="scale(this);"`

The full code:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="image" ><img src="http://libcom.org/files/images/library/black-square.jpg" width="50px" height="100px" onclick="scale(this);"/></div>
```

and the function itself:

```
function scale(e) {
   e.style.width="200px";
   e.style.height="300px";
}
```